# get selected option to appear at the top of the dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select input with a range of months starting Jan 2017. by default, the selected option is the current month/year. when you click the select input the selected option appears around 2 3rds of the way down the menu. My question is: is there any way to get the selected option to appear at the top of the menu. i.e scroll down the menu. this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/do8tn3c5/7/) should demonstrate what I mean. Thank you.

javascrtipt

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

cT = new Date();
M = cT.getMonth() + 1;
Y = cT.getFullYear();

setDateSelect();


function setDateSelect(){
 fm = 1;
 fy = 2017;
 lm = 12;
 ly = Y+6;

 while(fy < ly){
       $('#monthYear').append('<option>'+monthNames[fm -1]+' '+fy+'</option>');
     if (fm == 12) {
         fm = 0;
         fy++;
     }
      fm++;
 }
      $('#monthYear').val(monthNames[M - 1] + ' ' + Y);

}
```

html

```
<select id = "monthYear"></select>
```

Comment: There is; you can `prepend()` the selected `option` to the parent `select`. However you're making a lot of work for yourself as you will need to somehow put it back in its original place when a different option is chosen - assuming you don't want duplicates.

Comment: but what element would I be prepending to the select input?